# BufferedReader and BufferedWritter

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I have a .txt file. I want as soon as a line starts from '>' then, the first bullet symbol '•' that is encountered to be written as '>>•'. I use:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\text.txt"));
bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\text.txt"));

        while ((current_line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (current_line.length() > 1 && (current_line.charAt(0) == '>' || current_line.charAt(1) != '>'))  {
                found = true;
            }
            if ((found) && (current_line.length() > 1) && current_line.charAt(0) == '•') {
                bw.write(">>");
                found = false;
            }
        }
        br.close();
        bw.close();
```

But that gives as a result an.. empty .txt file? What do I do wrong? Thanks a lot

Comment: What encoding is used for the input file, output file, and source code?

Comment: You're reading and writing from/to **the same file**.

Comment: is the bullet point in the same line? do you want to write other lines as well?

Comment: No, it's aways in a different line, after '>' and is the first char

Comment: why not instead then say something like: line=readline(); if line.startsWith(">") line.replace(bullet, ">>.");
and then just write out every line?

Answer (score 1):

Where is the `bw.write(line); bw.write("\r\n");`?

```
try (br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\User\Desktop\\text.txt");
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\User\Desktop\\text-2.txt")) {

    String current_line;
    while ((current_line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (current_line.length() > 1 && (current_line.charAt(0) == '>' || current_line.charAt(1) != '>'))  {
            found = true;
        }
        if (found && current_line.startsWith("•")) {
            bw.write(">>");
            found = false;
        }
        bw.write(line);
        bw.write("\r\n"):
    }
}
```

Unfortunately you cannot write to the same file here.

Also backslashes must be escaped in Java strings.

It would be nicer to name `found` something like `tackleBullet`.

Comment: or close the file, save result, open and write again.

Comment: Use `System.lineSeparator()` (since Java 7) or `System.getProperty("path.separator");` (Java 6 or prior) instead of naive `"\r\n"`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza sorry, I am on Linux at home, and to create a text file for Windows I am forced on Linux to do just that `"\r\n"`. Especially I wanted to prevent `"\n"` being used by the lazy typers. Thanks for telling the OP however, of the official way to do it.